Want Blazor Server and Blazor WebAssembly both in solution, but dont like the .NET 8 Blazor WebApp
I'm trying to create a new project of Blazor in .NET 8 and the very first thing I realized is that the WebAssembly functions that enabled the app to be PWA are lost in the new Blazor App.
That's the first thing I didn't like of it, and then other issues came out. So I ended up creating the template of Blazor WebAssembly in .NET 6 and manually updating it to .NET 8. Surprinsingly, it worked with minor adjustments, but here's the thing:
I liked the way the new Blazor WebApp managed to change the views of authentication, but I want the true WebAssembly functionality that come with the previous Blazor WebAssembly.
Is there a way to mix the client and server like the .NET 6 WebAssembly but like having Blazor Wasm and Blazor Server working in separate?

There's a template called the Blazor WebAssembly Standalone App in Net 8 which is what I think you are looking for.

@MrCakaShaunCurtis I'm already using that template, but it doesn't have the identity pages in razor components because is wasm

@JoseManuelLepe You can scaffold the /account/ pages any time and add the identy customized as you want it, I don't understand your issues
